# Cannot connect to the data node when using docker to build a cluster

Tags: docker, dolphindb

When using docker to build a cluster, the data node cannot be connected, and an error that the cache engine is not turned on is displayed. I did not see in the manual that the cache engine must be turned on.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. if the configuration "datasync = 0", There is no need to open the cache engine at this time.
2. If datasync = 1, you must set cache engine must be set